# rxjs/combineLatest error after upgrade to nativescript-angular 5.2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, nativescript

After upgrading to nativescript-angular 5.0 I get an error: 
Property 'combineLatest' does not exist on type 'Observable
It seems that it is not possible anymore to write: Observabel.combineLatest()

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as Config from '../../config';


@Injectable()
export class CountryService {
    appSettings = require("application-settings");

    constructor( private _apiEndpoints: Config.ApiEndpoints, 
                private _http:Http,
                private _settings:Config.Settings) {
    }


    getPhonePrefix(): Observable<Object> {      
    return this._http.get(this._apiEndpoints.apiEndpoint + '/country/phone')
            .map(res => res.json());
    }


getCountryNameAndPrefix(): Observable<Array<Config.phonePrefix>> {
    return this.getPhonePrefix().combineLatest(this.getCountryName(),
        (phoneData, nameData) => {
            let resultData:Config.phonePrefix[] = [];
            Object.keys(nameData).forEach((key) => {
                let resultItem:Config.phonePrefix = {
                   countrycode: key, 
                   countryname: nameData[key], 
                   countryprefix: phoneData[key]
                };
                resultData.push(resultItem);
                resultData.sort((a,b) => {
                    if(a['countryname'] < b['countryname']) {
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                });
            });
             return resultData;
        });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling the static `combineLatest`, so your import should be:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest";
```

Note that the `import` uses `operator` rather than `observable`.